# Taking input using fgets(); and saves different than inputted

Tags: c, unix

I am taking 2 programs and linking them for a homework assignment, and it asks for user input, and saves a different value than the input. The code in program 1 is the professor's other than the print statements for debugging and others have had no issues with it. But i am curious why its not saving correctly.

**program 1:**

```
#include        <stdlib.h>
#include        <stdio.h>

#define         TEXT_LEN        256


//
//      Declarations go here:
//

//  PURPOSE:  To hold the computer's answer.
extern int      answer;

//  PURPOSE:  To, in a loop:
//      (1) get an integer that from the user by calling 'getGuess()',
//      (2) increment 'count',
//      (3) compare the user's guess with 'answer'
//        (3a) if they are equal, print how may guesses the user used and
//             quit the loop,
//        (3b) if the guess too high print print "Too high!\n"
//        (3c) if the guess too low print print "Too low!\n"
//      No parameters.  No return value.
extern
void            playGame        ();


//
//      Function and variables go here:
//

//  PURPOSE:  To keep track of the number of guesses the user used.
int             count   = 0;


//  PURPOSE:  To set 'answer' to the computer's answer.  No parameters.  No
//      return value.
void            generateAnswer  ()
{
  answer        = rand() % 256;
  printf("answer: %d",answer);
}
//  PURPOSE:  To ask the user for an integer, and to return it.  No parameters.
int     getGuess    ()
{
  char  numberText[TEXT_LEN];

  printf("Please guess my number in 0..255: ");
  fgets(numberText,TEXT_LEN,stdin);
  return(strtol(numberText,NULL,10));
}


 int    main    ()
{
  generateAnswer();
  playGame();
  return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**program 2:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define         TEXT_LEN        256

int answer;
int count;
void playGame();
int numberText;

void playGame()
{
 printf("user input: %d",numberText);
 getGuess();
 if( answer > numberText)
 {
  printf("Too Low!");
  count += 1;
 }
 if( answer < numberText)
 {
  printf("Too High!");
  count += 1;
 }
 if (answer == numberText)
 {
  count += 1;
  printf("Just right! It took %d tries",count);
  return;
 }
 playGame();
}
```

**output:**

```
[tplutz@cdmlinux CSC374]$ ./whole
    answer: 103user input: 0Please guess my number in 0..255: 23
    user input : -1078133976 Too Low!user input: 0Please guess my number in     0..255: 150
    user input : -1078133992 Too Low!user input: 0Please guess my number in 0..255: 103
    user input : -1078134008 Too Low!user input: 0Please guess my number in 0..255:`
```

Comment: `fgets()` is not in the posted code.

Comment: You have presented two source files, but they don't make up even *one* program.

Comment: im sorry. must not have copied it all. give me a moment

Comment: `numberText=getGuess();printf("user input: %d\n", numberText);`

Comment: Or if @BLUEPIXY was too terse for you, the `getGuess()` function *returns* the value of the guess.  It doesn't communicate it in any other way.  Your code ignores the return value, but assumes that variable `answer` has somehow been set to that value.

Comment: Ohh! Thanks so much, I was wondering about it not using the return value but did not think of that.

Comment: the playgame() function is recursive, it should be a do ... while loop instead.  The recursive feature has no positive exit other than the user guessing the correct number.  Which, a user could guess all 255 possible numbers before guessing the right number.   even then the user might keep re-guessing the same incorrect number, so the program never ends.  even recursion 255 deep is not a good plan.  the unlimited recursion of the posted code is a VERY BAD idea.

Comment: Yeah, am still new to programming, will do that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No assignment

```
getGuess();
if( answer > numberText)
```

Should be

```
answer = getGuess();
if( answer > numberText)
```

Wrote up answer from comments and moved to community, so OP can close this.

Credit: [@John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger)
[@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy)